# Posso usar uma variável para setar um caminho no FileStream?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um script de teste no Selenium Webdriver utilizando C# no qual leio dados de um arquivo `.txt` externo.

O caminho para o arquivo está fixo no script, indicando uma pasta no meu computador. Mas no futuro outras pessoas executarão este script em outros computadores, e terão que ajustar o caminho de forma manual diretamente no script.

É possível setar o caminho `C:\Users\...\myData.txt`  como sendo um tipo de variável, quero dizer, não sendo permanente no corpo do script?

Minha situação é a seguinte: possuo cerca de 15 projetos de teste na Solution Explorer do Visual Studio. Para cada projeto tenho que utilizar diferentes dados nos testes. Então é por isso que hoje tenho um caminho para o arquivo `.txt` descrito direto no script para cada projeto, para que cada um deles leia seu próprio arquivo `.txt`. Se eu setar uma variável para o caminho, eu poderia ler este caminho de um outro arquivo `.txt`, por exemplo, mas acredito que fazer isso seja redundante.

Aqui está parte do script:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Principal
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }

        public class DataTXT
        {
            public string example1{ get; set; }
            public string example2{ get; set; }
            public string example3{ get; set; }
            public string example4{ get; set; }
        }

        public static IEnumerable DataTXT
        {
            get
            {
                string linha;
                using (FileStream readFile =
                new FileStream(@"C:\Users\...\myData.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(readFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var column = line.Split(';');
                        yield return new DataTXT
                        {
                            example1 = column[0],
                            example2 = column[1],
                            example3 = column[2],
                            example4 = column[3]
                        };
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    readFile.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o caminho relativo, mesmo, e adicione o seu .txt de cada projeto na Solution Explorer, nos respectivos csprojs.

Imagine que a solution seja a raiz e posicione seu .txt no mesmo caminho relativo usado no `new FileStream(caminho)`.

Na Solution Explorer, clique com o direito no .txt e vá em Propriedades. Em Copy To Output Directory, escolha Copy if newer.

Comment: Muito obrigada @MarceloUchimura! Questão resolvida.